# NullPointerException: Google Spreadsheet, doInBackground

Tags: android, google-sheets

I get the NullPointerException and I can't figure out what's wrong. I've tried only to bring the necessary code. 
I have 3 classes: MainActivity, GoogleCommunicator and CustomAdapter.
The error is caused by following in CustomAdapter:

```
mActivity.updateBought(position, "1");
```

The errors I get are line 283 and 277 which are:

```
283: URL listFeedUrl = mWorksheet.getListFeedUrl();
277: private class UpdateBought extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
```

The logcat:

```
3011-3026/com.example.andb.apop_l6_google_communicator_app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.example.andb.apop_l6_google_communicator_app, PID: 3011
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.net.URL com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.WorksheetEntry.getListFeedUrl()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.andb.apop_l6_google_communicator_app.GoogleCommunicator$UpdateBought.doInBackground(GoogleCommunicator.java:283)
        at com.example.andb.apop_l6_google_communicator_app.GoogleCommunicator$UpdateBought.doInBackground(GoogleCommunicator.java:277)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    public GoogleCommunicator mGCom = new GoogleCommunicator(this,"torprode@gmail.com");
    TextView tvStatus;
    EditText etAdd;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);

        doSomeGoogleStuff();
        buttonListener();
        update();

    }

    private void doSomeGoogleStuff(){
        mGCom.setupFeed("mandatoryProject","BuyMe");
    }


    private void drawListview() {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, mGCom.listItem, mGCom.listBought);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_items);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }


    public void updateBought(int name, String bought) {
        mGCom.updateBought(name, bought);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }
}
```

GoogleCommunicator

```
public class GoogleCommunicator {

    //Spreadsheet communication
    private static final String mScope = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://docs.google.com/feeds";
    private MainActivity mActivity;
    private SpreadsheetService mSpreadSheetService;
    private SpreadsheetFeed mFeed;
    private String mSpreadsheetName;
    private String mWorksheetName;
    private SpreadsheetEntry mSpreadsheet;
    private WorksheetEntry mWorksheet; 
    private String itemName;
    private int itemNameIndex;
    private String itemBought;

    //Constructor
    public GoogleCommunicator(MainActivity activity, String email) {
        mEmail = email;
        mActivity = activity; //possibility for callback to method in activity class

    }


    //Method to be called from your application.
    //Creates an instance of SetupFeedTask (an AsyncTask) and executes it
    public void setupFeed(String spreadsheet_name, String worksheet_name){

        mSpreadsheetName = spreadsheet_name;
        mWorksheetName = worksheet_name;

        new SetupFeedTask().execute();
    }

    public void updateBought(int name, String bought) {
        itemNameIndex = name;
        itemBought = bought;
        new UpdateBought().execute();
    }

    //AsyncTask that handles network comminucation e.t.c.
    private class SetupFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        //Executes in its own "worker thread" and doesnt block the main UI thread
        @Override protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // Do work
            mToken = fetchToken();

            mSpreadSheetService = new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetService");
            mSpreadSheetService.setAuthSubToken(mToken);

            URL feed_url;
            try {
                feed_url = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
                mFeed = mSpreadSheetService.getFeed(feed_url, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
            }catch(MalformedURLException e){
                //TODO: handle exception
                Log.v(TAG, "MalformedURLException");
                return null;
            }catch(ServiceException e){
                //TODO: handle exception
                Log.v(TAG, "ServiceException");
                return null;
            }catch(IOException e){
                //TODO: handle exception
                Log.v(TAG, "IOException");
                return null;
            }

            try{

                List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = mFeed.getEntries();

                // Iterate through all of the spreadsheets returned
                for (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet : spreadsheets) {
                    if (spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText().equals(mSpreadsheetName)) {
                        List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = spreadsheet.getWorksheets();
                        //Iterate through worksheets
                        for (WorksheetEntry worksheet : worksheets) {
                            if (worksheet.getTitle().getPlainText().equals(mWorksheetName)) {
                                mSpreadsheet = spreadsheet;
                                mWorksheet = worksheet;

                                Log.v(TAG,"Spreadsheet and Worksheet is now setup.");

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }catch(ServiceException e){
                //TODO: handle exception
                Log.v(TAG, "Service Exception");
                return null;
            }catch(IOException e){
                //TODO: handle exception
                Log.v(TAG, "IO Exception");
                return null;
            }

            //Just for the example.. mToken not important to return
            return mToken;

        }

        //Call back that is called when doInBackground has finished.
        //Executes in main UI thread
        @Override protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //TODO: Notify rest of application, e.g.:
            // * Send broadcast
            // * Send message to a handler
            // * Call method on Activity
        }

        //Helper method
        private String fetchToken(){
            try {
                return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableException) {
                // GooglePlayServices.apk is either old, disabled, or not present, which is
                // recoverable, so we need to show the user some UI through the activity.

                //TODO:
                if(mActivity instanceof MainActivity){
                    ((MainActivity)mActivity).handleException(userRecoverableException);
                    if(D) Log.e(TAG,"UserRecoverableAuthException");

                }
            } catch (GoogleAuthException fatalException) {

                //TODO:
                //onError("Unrecoverable error " + fatalException.getMessage(), fatalException);
                if(D) Log.e(TAG,"GoogleAuthException");
            } catch (IOException ioException){

                if(D) Log.e(TAG,"IOException");
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

    private class UpdateBought extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                URL listFeedUrl = mWorksheet.getListFeedUrl();
                ListFeed listFeed = mSpreadSheetService.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);

                ListEntry row = listFeed.getEntries().get(itemNameIndex);

                row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("bought", itemBought);

                row.update();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ServiceException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

CustomAdapter

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    ArrayList boughtList;
    MainActivity mActivity = new MainActivity();

    CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> item, ArrayList<String> bought) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_listview, item);
        boughtList = bought;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater listViewInflater = (LayoutInflater.from(getContext()));
        final View customView = listViewInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview, parent, false);

        final String foodItem = getItem(position);
        TextView foodText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Item);
        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) customView.findViewById(R.id.cb_checked);

        foodText.setText(foodItem);

        String foodBought = String.valueOf(boughtList.get(position));
        int foodBoughtInt = Integer.parseInt(foodBought);
        if (foodBoughtInt == 1) {
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    System.out.println("Jep");
                    mActivity.updateBought(position, "1");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Nope");
                    mActivity.updateBought(position, "0");
                }
            }
        });

        return customView;
    }
}
```

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.net.URL com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.WorksheetEntry.getListFeedUrl()' on a null object reference` This error means that mWorksheet on line 283 is currently null. Are you sure that this code is executing first?

Answer (score 1):

You are encountering a race condition. You have to asynchronous tasks that execute, and the second asynchronous task depends on the first task to be done for it to work correctly. Because both tasks are done asynchronously, they are done in the background, on separate threads. Your `setupFeed` method is not done working, and then you start your `updateBought` method on a new thread. What happens is that `updateBought` begins while mWorksheet is still null. You will have to reorganize your code logic to avoid this race condition. What I have done in the past when I have two async tasks is to put the second asynchronous task in `onPostExecute()` of the first async task, because `onPostExecute` only occurs once `doInBackground` is finished.

[Here is an execellent article on AsyncTasks and Threads from the developer guides.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)